# multiplication_table function prints the results of a number passed to it

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, while-loop

The multiplication_table function prints the results of a number passed to it multiplied by 1 through 5. An additional requirement is that the result is not to exceed 25, which is done with the break statement. Fill in the blanks to complete the function to satisfy these conditions

```
def multiplication_table(number):
    # Initialize the starting point of the multiplication table
    multiplier = 1
    # Only want to loop through 5
    while multiplier <= 5:
        result = 1 
        # What is the additional condition to exit out of the loop?
        if ___ :
            break
        print(str(number) + "x" + str(multiplier) + "=" + str(result))
        # Increment the variable for the loop     
        ___ += 1

multiplication_table(3) 
# Should print: 3x1=3 3x2=6 3x3=9 3x4=12 3x5=15

multiplication_table(5) 
# Should print: 5x1=5 5x2=10 5x3=15 5x4=20 5x5=25

multiplication_table(8) 
# Should print: 8x1=8 8x2=16 8x3=24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if result > 25:`

and

`multiplier += 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
while multiplier <=5:
     result = 1
```

You might want to change this as this will give you a result of 1 for all multiplications

it should be

```
while multiplier <=5:
     result = multiplier * number
```

then finish off the rest from the other answer by @Girly Corner
It should look like this

```
def multiplication_table(number):
    # Initialize the starting point of the multiplication table
    multiplier = 1
    # Only want to loop through 5
    while multiplier <= 5:
        result = multiplier * number 
        # What is the additional condition to exit out of the loop?
        if result > 25 :
            break
        print(str(number) + "x" + str(multiplier) + "=" + str(result))
        # Increment the variable for the loop
        multiplier += 1

multiplication_table(3) 
# Should print: 3x1=3 3x2=6 3x3=9 3x4=12 3x5=15

multiplication_table(5) 
# Should print: 5x1=5 5x2=10 5x3=15 5x4=20 5x5=25

multiplication_table(8) 
# Should print: 8x1=8 8x2=16 8x3=24
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
def multiplication_table(number):
# Initialize the starting point of the multiplication table
  multiplier = 1
# Only want to loop through 5
    while multiplier <= 5:
      result = number * multiplier
    # What is the additional condition to exit out of the loop?
      if result > 25 :
        break
      print(str(number) + "x" + str(multiplier) + "=" + str(result) , end =' ')
    # Increment the variable for the loop
      multiplier += 1
    print()

multiplication_table(3)     
multiplication_table(5)     
multiplication_table(8)
```

Output:

```
3x1=3 3x2=6 3x3=9 3x4=12 3x5=15 
5x1=5 5x2=10 5x3=15 5x4=20 5x5=25 
8x1=8 8x2=16 8x3=24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def multiplication_table(number):
# Initialize the starting point of the multiplication table
multiplier = 1
# Only want to loop through 5
while multiplier <= 5:
    result = number * multiplier
    # What is the additional condition to exit out of the loop?
    if result > 25 :
        break
    print(str(number) + "x" + str(multiplier) + "=" + str(result))
    # Increment the variable for the loop
    multiplier += 1

multiplication_table(3) 
# Should print: 3x1=3 3x2=6 3x3=9 3x4=12 3x5=15

multiplication_table(5) 
# Should print: 5x1=5 5x2=10 5x3=15 5x4=20 5x5=25

multiplication_table(8) 
# Should print: 8x1=8 8x2=16 8x3=24
```

1. If we are to fill in the blanks for this question, for the first blank
   i.e result = _______ would be that since we are expecting the result of
   the product of the number by the multiplier, we should insert **"number *
   multiplier"**
2. For the second blank i.e. if ___ :, we need to make sure that the
   **product** **(multiplication of the "number" by "multiplier")** of the
   "result" for example if you take the second instance
   "multiplication_table(5)" does not exceed 25.

   So for that we need to put a threshold or a limit where "if the result
   (multiplication of number by multiplier) try's to exceed number 25, then
   the loop should stop".

   The threshold would be "if result > 25".
3. For the third blank i.e ___ += 1, since we are required to multiply the
   given number, for instance if we take the first instance
   "multiplication_table(3)" we need to keep running the numbers from 1 to 5
   (1,2,3,4,5) otherwise it will end up in an infinite loop because we start
   the multiplier from number 1, but there isn't any command or instruction
   in the code or script where it say's to continue multiplying the
   number by the multiplier through the number range of 1 to 5.

   Hence, we need to input "multiplier" so that the program would continue
   to run the
   numbers from 1 to 5 and also the program won't be stuck in an infinite
   loop.